# HTML5 any JQuery option instead of Flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a big question to ask.

http://www.potterybarn.com/design-studio/tool/design_your_own_bed.html

This is a website which has a "Design your own web solution" and i would like to make something exactly the same using HTML5 and Jquery or whatever somebody suggest. Which plugins do i need and what do i need to search for befora i even start the project. My project is prety simple. I have a image with some elements. Elements can change color or even element can be replaced by other element. And that is it. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are asking which plugins you need to use for doing exactly the same thing, I can tell you which frameworks/plugins [this specific website](http://www.potterybarn.com/design-studio/tool/design_your_own_bed.html) is using:

- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)
- [Coremetrics](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/marketing-solutions/coremetrics/)

Instead of using jquery, the are taking dojo for their needs.

---

The answer of the question 'what additional javascript/jquery frameworks/plugins do I need to make exactly the same thing?' is **none**.

You could do this in plain javascript without any framework! Frameworks just make your life easier, but you cannot come around the need of a good concept, you need to develop.

---

**Edit**

I think the best approach for developing such thing is using the [HTML5 Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_Tutorial). The canvas element is like an "image" you can easily manipulate via pure javascript. My favourite tutorial for canvas is http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/. There you can find lots of cool features and examples of how to use the canvas element.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do that even more simple and is there a demo which shows me what can i do. Can i do that with only HTML5?